# Group ID being ignored when creating NotificationChannel

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm migrating my apps to Android O (API 26), notification channel group ID always got ignored when creating NotificationChannel:

```
NotificationManager nm;
nm.createNotificationChannelGroup(new NotificationChannelGroup("test_group", "Test"));
NotificationChannel newCh = new NotificationChannel("test_channel:id123", "Test", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NORMAL);
newCh.setGroup("test_group");
nm.createNotificationChannel(newCh);

NotificationChannel ch = nm.getNotificationChannel("test_channel:id123"); // ch.getGroup() is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use colon ":" in channel ID, change ":" to other characters like underscore "_" will work.