# What is correct way to put notifications into stack as in Telegram in android Oreo?

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I have an [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ActiveNotifications/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/activenotifications/ActiveNotificationsFragment.java) app that can to group notifications as in the Telegram messenger.

The build build tools is 26.0.2. Compile and target SDK verions are 27.
For API 26 and above I added some code in *onViewCreated()* method :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannelGroup group = new NotificationChannelGroup(NOTIFICATION_GROUP, "messages");
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannelGroup(group);

    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channel_some", "channel_some", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    channel.enableLights(true);
    channel.setGroup(NOTIFICATION_GROUP);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

And use other constructor with notification channel id to create NotificationCompat.Builder:

```
final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity(), "channel_some")
```

But notifications are not grouped as it was in API 24 and 25. Which way is correct to group different notifications (example - Telegram messenger) in API 26 and above?

**UPDATE:**
It example works with compile and target SDK of 25 version. How to use it with SDK of 26 version and above?

Comment: **maybe** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886170/group-id-being-ignored-when-creating-notificationchannel

Comment: no, there are different problems.